# Which global scientific platforms exist to access ocean science-related data?

Tags: oceanography, database

I am looking for a database where I can access 18O data from planktonic foraminifera, but so far, I have only come across the [PANGAEA](https://www.pangaea.de/) database. Since this site is primarily maintained by German research institutes, are there any international databases or other national databases available?

Comment: Pangaea is an international data repository. The fact that it is hosted at a german institute has really no consequence on its content. Most of the geochemistry data from the international scientific drilling expeditions (which produced most of the d18O record) are deposited in Pangaea. The [NOAA](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/paleo-search/) website might have additional datasets but the bulk of them, if deposited somewhere, will be in Pangaea.

Comment: Ah nice I didn´t know that! I Thought it is only a national database :)

Comment: Additionally, this [atlas](https://essd.copernicus.org/articles/14/2553/2022/) of Late Quaternary foram isotopes might be of interest to you.